# Diagnosing Internet Spike Issues?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

When playing games or streaming videos I experience a spike that happens at least once or so a minute. I just almost completely lose any speed I just had, and after a few seconds it goes back up. Other devices on my network experience no connectivity issues. Via both wireless and wired connections I not experience any issues. Only on one computer are their issues. I've tried two different wireless adapters for the computer, both of which experienced the same issues despite working fine on other computers.

The computer in discussion is a custom built computer. Is there anyway to diagnos what is causing the problem here? Could it be some hardware problem causing the issue, or is it something else? I don't know how to troubleshoot such a problem once I've eliminated the possibility that the network or connection device is not at fault.

Comment: There is a possibility of a software installed on the machine that may cause that spike. Maybe a virus reporting back to its command and control server, iTunes (as an example) attempting to update all apps. You may try to install some sort of bandwidth monitoring tool on that PC and check if there are any incoming / outgoing connection, and find out what application is doing it. (Never had to monitor my bandwidth so I can't recommend anything for now sorry, maybe other users have something)

Comment: Is any other software running? Chat, email, weather-checker, "social media" etc? Certainly sounds like the sort of thing you get from an overly-frequent overly-hoggish program checking/updating, so start with shutting down all programs other than the one you are playing. The virus angle is worth checking, but it may well be a thing you invited in and don't consider a virus.